# CSV upload showing umlauts but it doesn't upload – and „ or “

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fgetcsv

Im having issues with a csv upload script where I need to upload German text into a mysql database for translation purposes.

Everything is UTF8 but when it runs the script and inserts into the database. All the characters are there, umluats show fine but the – (&mdash) and „ or “ just go in blank.

The snippet of text im trying to upload

Actual text in CSV = "Testing –  Seit über  „Es ist“ Das Unternehmen."

Database after upload = "Testing   Seit über  Es ist Das Unternehmen."

It uploads the umlauts but just puts a space where the dash and quotes should be.

The CSV is also encoded in utf-8

If I take the utf8_encode() off then the insert breaks at the first special character.

Here is my script

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once("../cfg/database.php");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
extract($_POST);

$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
$data = array();

$count = 0;
if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size'])) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==FALSE) {
        if ($count != 0) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name SET `text` = '" . utf8_encode($data[5]) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        $count++;
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have searched and searched and can not find a solution.

EDIT: Note to self, do not rely on excel to correctly save the encoding of your csv to UTF-8. Just use notepad :)

Comment: I am no mysql guy, but: is "SET NAMES" limited to names or does it set the allowed encoding for content too ?

Comment: SET NAMES just indicates what character set the client will use so in this case I want to use UTF8 so it should cover it all.

Comment: I would have expected something like "set characterset", but if you already checked that this can't be the reason.

Comment: Fixed it. Saving via excel to encode didn't actually make the csv UTF-8. I opened in notepad and saved from there and tried to upload and it worked once I took off utf8_encode() from my insert query. Thank you Marged as your first question sparked the creative juices :) Oh and a good nights sleep too ;)

Comment: glad to hear I could help. And by the way: in my timezone it is 10:00 in the morning ;-)